# Heroku app stops working after some time and needs reopening

Tags: node.js, heroku, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have uploaded a node.js server to heroku. Its purpose is to send notifications to my users. It is listening to firebase database and sending notifications. The problem is that after an hour or so of working it stops sending notifications and when I open app on heroku it starts working again. That is really strange. Any ideas? My code is similar to this one

```
var firebase = require('firebase');
var request = require('request');
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));

var API_KEY = "..."; // Your Firebase Cloud Server API key

firebase.initializeApp({
  serviceAccount: ".json",
  databaseURL: "https://.firebaseio.com/"
});
ref = firebase.database().ref();

function listenForNotificationRequests() {
  var requests = ref.child('notificationRequests');
  ref.on('child_added', function(requestSnapshot) {
    var request = requestSnapshot.val();
    sendNotificationToUser(
      request.username, 
      request.message,
      function() {
        request.ref().remove();
      }
    );
  }, function(error) {
    console.error(error);
  });
};

function sendNotificationToUser(username, message, onSuccess) {
  request({
    url: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type' :' application/json',
      'Authorization': 'key='+API_KEY
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      notification: {
        title: message
      },
      to : '/topics/user_'+username
    })
  }, function(error, response, body) {
    if (error) { console.error(error); }
    else if (response.statusCode >= 400) { 
      console.error('HTTP Error: '+response.statusCode+' - '+response.statusMessage); 
    }
    else {
      onSuccess();
    }
  });
}

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    listenForNotificationRequests();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [Heroku dev center](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours):

> Free dynos are unique because they go to sleep after 30 minutes of inactivity.

Are you using a free tier?

Comment: This is likely the answer, but you're better off re-wording your question so it sounds like an answer and not a comment ;)

Comment: Yes can you tell a little more. So I have to pay for this not to happen?

Comment: Ok. I added my heroku app site here http://www.herokuping.com/ . Should be fine now.